# Deleting works for everything but the first message

Tags: php

I am coding the portion of my web game that handles the mailing system, so players can communicate in-game. In your inbox, you need to be able to delete mail as well as read so I put in a delete button and make it so when you click it, if it gets "deletemsg" it puts the mail_id in a function that deletes the message from the database. This works good, except that when you delete everyone message except the one that is top-most, it won't work. The top message just sits there, if you click its delete button, it still remains after the page refreshs.

So, if you have three messages, message #1, #2, and #3. Let's say #1 is at the top of the inbox, then #2 and #3. If you hit the delete button for #3 and #2, the messages delete fine, but come message #1, it doesn't do anything.

I've tried looking at the code for errors, but I have no clue why all but the last message in a user's inbox won't delete.

```
<?php
                            $query = "SELECT * FROM mail WHERE receiver='$char_name' ORDER BY time DESC;";
                            $result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die(mysqli_error($db));
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                $mail_id = $row['mail_id'];
                                echo("<tr>");
                                echo("<td>" . date("F j, Y, g:i a", $row['time']));
                                echo("<td>" . $row['sender']);
                                echo("<td>" . $row['subject']);
                                echo("<td><a href='mail-read.php?mail_id=" . $row['mail_id']. "' class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark'>Read</a>");
                                echo("
                                        <form action='mail.php' method='get'>
                                            <button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' name='deletemsg'>Delete</button></tr></td>
                                        </form>
                                        ");

                            }

                        if(isset($_GET['deletemsg'])) {
                            delete_mail($mail_id);
                            echo("<div class='alert alert-success'><strong>Successfully deleted message!</strong></div>");
                        }

                    ?>
```

## Delete Function on a whole different .php that's linked to this one

```
function delete_mail($mail_id) {
global $db;
$query = "DELETE FROM mail WHERE mail_id='$mail_id'";
mysqli_query($db, $query) or die(mysqli_error($db));
return 1;
}
```

Comment: Your <form> doesn't specify the ID of the message to delete? In fact it looks like it works on `$mail_id` which is an artifact of your while loop.

Comment: Well, I need the mail id to know which message to delete from the database.

Comment: The only place `$mail_id` is defined is part of the while loop when _READING_ your mail, you need to perform the delete prior to reading mail, and to specify the ID as part of the request when the button is pressed. Looking at your code, your delete only works on the last row's `$mail_id` value.

Comment: My mail page pulls up all of the user's messages at once, and each one of them needs a delete button next to them, I am unsure how to make it so the delete button is associated with the correct mail_id.

Comment: Why not use check boxes with the values as the ID, then you can run through the array and it also allows users to multi delete messages instead of 1 by 1. You also need to update your code, if I was to say send a get request to that page such as `game.php?deletemsg=1 OR 1=1` It would wipe all your messages. Your current script is open to SQL injection.

Comment: That's a good point, I'll have to do that. What do you recommend to do to prevent SQL injection here?

Comment: @user3148270 your best prevention against SQL injection is to switch to prepare statements, also you might want to add some protection so that a user can only delete his own messages in your function.

Comment: You are already using mysqli so implement prepared statements : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php they are easy to use and provide good protection.